# tuples of RGB colors to surfarray in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have some array of complex numbers z, which I want to convert to rgb values with function ncol. Then I want to use it to create pygame syrfarray. Here example

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
z =  np.array([[(complex(-(x/2),-(y/2))) for x in range(2)]for y in range(2)])
def ncol(z):
    if cmath.phase(z)>180:
        w = (255,255,255)
    else:
        w = (125,125,0)
    return w
fz = np.frompyfunc(ncol,1,1)
w = fz(z)
print(w)
```

How could I translate it to surfarray of pygame?
I tried

```
pygame.surfarray.blit_array(surf,w)
```

But it gives

```
ValueError: Unsupported array element type
```

As I understand z has shape (2,2) and right shape for surfarray have to be (2,2,3)

**Answer given by skrx**

```
w = np.array([list(arr) for arr in w])
```

Comment: there seems to be a problem with the z value you provided. If I copy-paste your line of code I don't actually get a valid statement

Comment: Yes sorry. I try to update with actual code later

Answer (score 3):

The shape of your array has to match the size of your surface. This means if you look at the output of `numpy.array(z).shape` the output has to be `(width, height, 3)` to the size of your surface. You can check the width and height of your surface using `surf.get_width` and `surf.get_height`.

Furthermore the third element of the shape tuple has to be `3` because the surface uses a 3-Tuple to represent the RGB color values.

Comment: Yeh, I know this. So is the question how could I convert z from [[(255, 170, 0) (255, 170, 0)] [(255, 170, 0) (0, 127, 255)]][(255, 170, 0) (255, 170, 0)] with shape (2,2) to [[[255, 170, 0] [255, 170, 0]] [[255, 170, 0] [0, 127, 255]]][[255, 170, 0] [255, 170, 0]] which had shape (2,2,3)

Answer (score 2):

Try to rearrange your array in this way and then either use [`pygame.surfarray.make_surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.make_surface) or `pygame.surfarray.blit_array`.

```
import numpy as np
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

z = np.array([
    [(255, 170, 0), (255, 170, 0)],
    [(255, 170, 0), (0, 127, 255)],
    [(255, 170, 0), (255, 170, 0)],
    ])
print(z.shape)
# Either use `make_surface` to create a new surface ...
surface = pg.surfarray.make_surface(z)
# or create the surface first and then use `blit_array` to fill it.
surface2 = pg.Surface(z.shape[:2])
pg.surfarray.blit_array(surface2, z)
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    screen.blit(surface, (50, 50))
    screen.blit(surface2, (50, 100))

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: M472  simply repeat what I have asked. I have array z with shape (2,2) where elements are objects like this (255,255,255).  I've tried to use z = np.array(z) but it don't work. It has no effect on array structure. z array is creatd with some function broadcasted to other array of shape(2,2) , using frompyfunc

Comment: I got it to work by converting your `w` np.array into a Python list and back into an array: `w = np.array([list(arr) for arr in w])` I'm not sure if there's a better way, I don't have much experience with numpy.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was seeking for!